# Viewing a .ERWIN file

Tags: erd, erwin

How can one open/view a .erwin file if your company does not have an ERWIN licence?

Is it possible?

Requesting an alternatively formatted file is not an option.

Comment: do you have visio? this might be an option: http://help.lockergnome.com/office2/import-ERWin-ER1-Visio--ftopict768666.html

Comment: the thread suggests using a Visio 2003 database template to open the file.  I do have Visio 2003, but the database template is not there..

Comment: Install a trial version for 30 days, that should do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try ERwin's [community edition software](http://erwin.com/products/data-modeler/community-edition), though as the comments point out, the 25-object limit will make complex models unviewable.

Comment: Just FYI - the community edition only allows up to 25 objects. And the read-only edition is $1,000 (that's not a typo).

Comment: The 25 object limit makes community edition worthless in just about every real world scenario.

Comment: Oh my - good thing I saw this, was downloading that mammoth of a software to open a file sent by a client which definitely contains more than 25 objects. Who *are* these guys?